# How can I adjust a coefplot for the constant value of categorical variable estimation?

Tags: stata, coefplot

I have a dataset in Stata that looks something like this

```
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         dv2 |      1,904    .5395645     .427109  -1.034977   1.071396
        xvar |      1,904    3.074055    1.387308          1          5
```

with `xvar` being a categorical independent variable and `dv2` a dependent variable of interest.

I am estimating a simple model with the categorical variable as a dummy:

```
 reg dv2 ib4.xvar
eststo myest 

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     1,904
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 1899)      =     13.51
       Model |  9.60846364         4  2.40211591   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  337.540713     1,899  .177746558   R-squared       =    0.0277
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0256
       Total |  347.149177     1,903  .182422058   Root MSE        =     .4216

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         dv2 | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        xvar |
          A  |    .015635   .0307356     0.51   0.611     -.044644     .075914
          B  |   .1435987    .029325     4.90   0.000     .0860861    .2011113
          C  |   .1711176   .0299331     5.72   0.000     .1124124    .2298228
          E  |   .1337754   .0295877     4.52   0.000     .0757477    .1918032
             |
       _cons |    .447794    .020191    22.18   0.000     .4081952    .4873928
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the results. As you can see B, C and E have larger effect than D which is the excluded category.

However, `coefplot` does not account for the in categorical variable the coefficient is composite true_A=D+A.

```
coefplot myest, scheme(s1color) vert
```

[image]

As you can see the plot shows the constant to be the largest coefficient, while the other to be smaller.

Is there a systematic way I can adjust for this problem and plot the true coefficients and SEs of each category?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If D is the reference category, it shouldn't have a coefficient associated with it. It appears that the value labelled 'D' in the plot is in fact the constant (0.44), which suggests some mis-labelling has occurred. I would double check your code for your `coefplot` command.

Comment: Apologies, if this is mistaken, but my understanding of regressions where the independent variable is a categorical one, is that the constant term is the estimated effect (conditional mean of y given x) for the excluded category: am I wrong?

Comment: We need to be clear about the difference between plotting coefficients and plotting estimated effects. Coefficients are the values output in your regression table and can be plotted using `coefplot`, while estimated effects (i.e. in a linear regression, adding the constant coefficient and the coefficient from a level of the categorical independent variable) can be plotted using `margins` and `marginsplot`. Check out the help files for those commands.

Comment: Dear @Cybernike, thanks a lot for your suggestion: it is indeed very helpful. Is there any chance you would be able to illustrate how this works? I am not very familiar with the Stata environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your second comment, here is an example of how you can use `marginsplot` to plot estimated effects from a linear regression.

```
sysuse auto, clear
replace price = price/100
reg price i.rep78, cformat(%9.2f)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
          2  |      14.03      23.56     0.60   0.554       -33.04       61.10
          3  |      18.65      21.76     0.86   0.395       -24.83       62.13
          4  |      15.07      22.21     0.68   0.500       -29.31       59.45
          5  |      13.48      22.91     0.59   0.558       -32.28       59.25
             |
       _cons |      45.65      21.07     2.17   0.034         3.55       87.74
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

margins i.rep78, cformat(%9.2f)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       rep78 |
          1  |      45.65      21.07     2.17   0.034         3.55       87.74
          2  |      59.68      10.54     5.66   0.000        38.63       80.73
          3  |      64.29       5.44    11.82   0.000        53.42       75.16
          4  |      60.72       7.02     8.64   0.000        46.68       74.75
          5  |      59.13       8.99     6.58   0.000        41.18       77.08
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

marginsplot
```

Note that these values are the constant plus the appropriate coefficient.

And then using the `marginsplot` command we can produce the following plot, which includes the marginal estimates and confidence intervals:

[image]